# How to retrieve specific data of a specific user with UID from a Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am totally new in Java coding. Currently, I am trying to get "specific" data from my firebase realtime database. In my case, I want to use UserID to get the latitude and longitude in the HostID. However, I cannot get the data as it is from different account. I have do some research regarding to my question. I still do not know how can I get the latitude and longitude in HostID when I use UserID.

Below is how I store my data to the database.

```js
    private void saveDatatoDatabase(Location location) {
        String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

        //Access to database
        rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = rootNode.getReference("HostID");

        //Get the lat and log to the database
        TrackingIDClass IDclass = new TrackingIDClass(latitude, longitude);

        reference.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("TrackingID").child("ID").setValue(IDclass);
    }
```

Here is my database data.

[data from realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcLKN.png)

Here is how I retrieve data using the same host account.

```js
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34,151);
       // LatLng lastLocationPlaced = sydney;

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("TrackingID").child("ID");

        ValueEventListener listener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
                String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);

                Double Latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                Double Longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

                LatLng latLng = new LatLng (Latitude,Longitude);
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title("Lat:" + Latitude+" Lon:" + Longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                //lastLocationPlaced = latLng;

                mMap.animateCamera((CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,12.0f)));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Now I facing problem on the way to get the latitude when I use UserID account. I am really not sure how I can proceed from here, I see no method to go forward. Please advice. Thank you very much.

**Update!!!**

Now I have made some changes on the way to search for the TrackingID.

```js
 private void isTrackingID() {
        String userTrackingID = enterTracking.getText().toString().trim();
        //Long userTrackingIDNumber = Long.parseLong(userTrackingID);

        Toast.makeText(this, "testing = " + userTrackingID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());

        Query query = reference.orderByChild("TrackingID/ID").equalTo(userTrackingID);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                  Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                   enterTracking.setError(null);

                   String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       String Latitudevalue = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("latitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for lol", Latitudevalue);
                       String Longitudevalue = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("longitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for latitude", Longitudevalue);

                      String latitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot1.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
                      String longitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot1.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);

                       Double Latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudefromDatabase);
                       Double Longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudefromDatabase);

                      Intent intent = new Intent(Latitude_Longitude.this, MapsActivity.class);

                      intent.putExtra("latitude", Latitude);
                      intent.putExtra("longitude", Longitude);

                       startActivity(intent);

                   }
               }else {
                    enterTracking.setError("Invalid Tracking ID from database");
                    enterTracking.requestFocus();
                   }
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

After adding these code, the logcat keep showing "W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "TrackingID/ID"' at HostID/q6jJMcxtTxMkxiktl6K4eDBSrRP2 to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance" and the output from the Edittext keep saying "Invalid Tracking ID from database." I dont know where is the mistake...

Comment: You need to adjust your database rules in the Firebase console to enable access to other user's data.

Comment: @Cole Tustin How should I adjust the database rules and how should I get the location without knowing the UID of the HostID?

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have use the Log.d(TAG , databaseError.getMessage()); already, but android studio said there is an error on the TAG word and need to take actions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to find the user's UID by some logic, possibly with a query based on location [Order by Child](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#data-order).

If you already know the user's UID, you can use it in your typical [read method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once), but will require that [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions) allow any user to read any other user's information

Comment: Actually how do the query and order by child work? Because my project need to obtain the location from the host which taking the Tracking ID. So, the program should should search for the Tracking ID but not the hostID....

Comment: the OrderByChild() uses the path specified within from the base reference, say if you have a list of users, and you want to find all users who are in a specific longitude - you would use `("users").orderByChild("position/longituted")` - this sorts the list of 'users' based on the values within `position/longitude` which allows you to then find values that are within a range or equal too X

Comment: I have made the changes according to your suggestion and I have updated the post. However, the program still showing the "W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "TrackingID/ID"' at HostID/q6jJMcxtTxMkxiktl6K4eDBSrRP2 to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance" and the log of "checking, this is value message" still not showing...

Comment: this warning is letting you know that your rules don't currently support indexing and will require a set of rules to trigger an "index on" event. of which you need to specify the path to that. generation of the index is typically a once-off procedure for that field variable - you can read about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: Which mean my coding (with latest update) is correct and now the problem is on the realtime database rules only right?

Comment: correct, I don't know the full scope of your project but, it appears ok. The fact that you have that error means it is making the request, it just can't find an index table relevant which is how firebase handles queries